# View is different during preview and run time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am creating a sign up page. When i run this on the iPhone 4s, part of the Sign Up button is being covered up. Therefore i decided to add a scrollview. On the left side is how the screen looks like in the storyboard and on the right is how it looks like during preview.
[image]

However when i run it, this is what i get
[image]

Why is the label pushed down by so much? I have added a red background to the scrollview. The scrollview starts right below the navigation bar. But the label is being pushed down by so much. Why is this so? and How do i fix it?

Comment: Have you added any constraints to your layout at all?

Comment: yes i did add constraints to all my views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like some constraint error. I am not pretty sure if you using or not. My advice would be; add some fixed height of the label. Make sure that the "Sign Up" button has bottom constraint, too.

Comment: i have a fixed height constraint for the label the button and all the textfields and a bottom space to superview constraint for the button

Comment: Could be inset problem too. You can change the "Adjust Scroll View Insets" of the scroll view from the Interface.